# A problem faced while using dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's a file called *dictionaries.py* which has the following code:

```
commands={1:"GO", 2:"LOCKED", 3:"CLOSED", 4:"CHECKED"}
```

Here's another file called *main.py* which takes input from user and stores it in a variable called *enter*. Now this variable contains the dictionary to be accessed from *dictionaries.py* which has been imported. I have written the following code but it gives me an error saying -

> selection = dictionaries.enter  AttributeError: module 'dictionaries' has
> no attribute 'enter'

```
import dictionaries

enter = input("enter your selection: ")
selection = dictionaries.enter
print(selection)
```

Comment: try this, ```selection = dictionaries.command.get(int(enter), "not found")```, command is the variable defined inside file ``dictionaries``

Comment: you cannot get an item from a dictionary using the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) notation: `object.attribute`. you must use the [getitem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) notation: `container[slice]`

Comment: @Sushanth it doesn't work it says

selection = dictionaries.commands.get(int(enter), "not found")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'engine'

Comment: I'm a Python programmer who has lately been spending a lot of time in SRE land and writing Jenkins pipelines, which use Groovy. Groovy allows things like `someMapping.someKey`, and if that is an array, even `someMapping.someKey.3.someAttr`. It still feels like madness to me.

Comment: (but then, Groovy also silently maps `someClass.attr` to `someClass.getAttr()` so you can write transparent properties without any boilerplate code. It's a weird language to begin with)

Comment: @SriramMadduri sounds like you entered "engine" in your user input field, rather than one of the integers you seem to be looking for....

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax to access the values in the dictionary.

```
import dictionaries

enter = input("enter your selection: ")
selection = dictionaries[enter]  # how to access dictionary
print(selection)
```

**Updated**

```
# Import the specific dictionary we want to access
from dictionaries import commands

try:
    enter = input("enter your selection: ")
    # All of the dictionary keys are integers so
    # we need to cast from string to int
    enter_as_int = int(enter)  
    selection = commands[enter_as_int]  # how to access dictionary
    print(selection)
except Exception as e:
    # if the user enters a non-int or an int that is not in 
    # commands then we can expect an Exception
    print(f"There was an error: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: I'm looking to import the whole dictionary from another file.To explain it better, User enters a input(lets say commands) and this should be imported from the dictionaries.py which has the variable commands

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable I get this error

Answer (score 0):

If your library is:

```py
# ./dictionaries.py
commands = {1: "GO", 2: "LOCKED", 3: "CLOSED", 4: "CHECKED"}
```

Then your usage should be:

```py
# ./main.py

import dictionaries

# Assume the user gives you valid input. In real life,
# you should write some error handling here
entry = input("enter your selection: ")

# entry is assumed to be something like `commands`
user_selected_dict = getattr(dictionaries, entry)

# this should work now
assert user_selected_dict[1] == "GO"
```

Comment: I'm looking to import the whole dictionary from another file.To explain it better, User enters a input(lets say commands) and this should be imported from the dictionaries.py which has the variable commands

Comment: @SriramMadduri updated to match your expected output

Answer (score 0):

When you use it like
'selection = dictionaries.enter' python will serch for 'enter' as an attribute and not as value try it like 'selection = dictionaries[enter]'
it should work like this

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable I get this error